# Error: Class Methods may only be declared on a type

Tags: ios, swift

Hi I had written some code (using swift):

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

func timerFireMethod(timer1: NSTimer) { }

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    func timerFireMethod(timer1: NSTimer) { }
    var greytitle : UIImage = UIImage(named:"AppTitle.png")
    var redtitle : UIImage = UIImage(named:"AppTitleRed.png")

    @IBOutlet var maintitle: UIImageView

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib

         class func scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(_ seconds: NSTimeInterval = 0.1,
            target timer1m: AnyObject!,
            selector timer1: Selector,
            userInfo nil: AnyObject!,
            repeats true: Bool) -> NSTimer!

        maintitle.image = greytitle

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

And where it says class func I get a error

```
"Class Methods may only be declared on a type"
```

I know it's a pretty novice question but if anyone could explain what I'm doing wrong it would be greatly appreciated! Also I noticed 4 lines are highleted as code but they are code.

Comment: What is `class func scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` trying to do?

Comment: Ah, what you have written isn't right at all. Lemme add an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a timer you should use

```
var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: "someFunction", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that you are trying to write a method (`timerWithInterval`)inside another method (`viewDidLoad`). You also aren't creating a timer in the right way. I see you declared a class function to do this so I will use that as an example. Do this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib


}
class func scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(_ seconds: NSTimeInterval = 0.1,
        target timer1m: AnyObject!,
        selector timer1: Selector,
        userInfo nil: AnyObject!,
        repeats doesRepeat: Bool) -> NSTimer!{

    //maintitle.image = greytitle
    var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(seconds, target: timer1m, selector: timer1, userInfo: nil, repeats:doesRepeat)
    (NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop()).addTimer(timer, forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode)
}
```

Comment: What? This doesn't make sense either. `class func` doesn't make sense. He is trying to create an NSTimer. Not define a function.

Comment: This was his original code. I didn't change it other that reform mating it correctly which would solve the error.

Comment: Yes, it was his original code, but still, even this won't compile. You are defining a function that returns an NSTimer... but not returning anything. You are setting an image to `greytitle` but that isn't in the scope of the new method, etc...

Comment: Edited it to do what the OP was *probably* looking for.

Comment: It is possible to create nested functions, but of course only with implementation and not type methods (class). Question wasn't clear.